# @Id annotation not working in Hibernate with Oracle

Tags: java, database, oracle, hibernate

I am learning hibernate from [this book](http://www.amazon.in/Beginning-Hibernate-Novice-Professional/dp/1590596935) and I am trying to save an entity Book.

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;



import javax.persistence.Id;


@Entity
public class Book {

@Id

private int id;

private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}



    Book book1 = new Book();

    book1.setName("Sample");
    session.save(book1);
```

But this code works only one time and that too when there is no data in Books table, because each time it generates '0' as the primary key id.Below is the exception trace.

```
ERROR: HHH000346: Error during managed flush 

[org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement]
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1403)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:473)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3133)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2370)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:467)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:220)

Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (SPRING.SYS_C0015610) violated

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1059)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:225)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:53)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:943)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1150)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4798)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4875)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1361)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
    ... 19 more
```

Book says:

> By default, the @Id annotation will automatically determine the most appropriate primary
>   key generation strategy to use—you can override this by also applying the @GeneratedValue
>   annotation

However, if I use @GeneratedValue annotation with @ID the code works fine and each time a new primary key id is generated. This scenario doesn't make sense to me. Am I missing anything or is there any db specific issue?

```
CREATE TABLE BOOK(
ID INTEGER,
NAME VARCHAR2(50)
);

ALTER TABLE BOOK ADD PRIMARY KEY(ID);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate use  **assigned** as  default generator strategy if there is no  element . In this case, your application assigns the id of entity. 
If you want hibernate will take care of auto generation id then you should use GeneratedValue or any another id Generated strategy

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
```

[here](https://github.com/techguy-bhushan/kickhibernate/tree/master/src/main/java/com/kickwithhibernate/generatorclassesinhibernate) are some examples

You id type is int

```
private int id;
```

When you first time insert value then jvm will assign id default value 0 so hibernate easily insert id with 0 value,
Now when your again try to insert value because there is no id generator strategy  then again jvm set id default value 0 and when hibernate try to insert it with id 0 value then its throw **ConstraintViolationException**  exception because id with 0 value already exist in database.
So if you want hibernate with auto assign the Id for your entity you can use jpa specific @GeneratedValue strategy (AUTO/IDENTITY/SEQUENCE/TABLE) 
or another hibernate strategy which will take care of assign id for Entity

```
      increment
      sequence
      hilo
      native
      identity
      seqhilo
      uuid
      guid
      select
      foreign
      sequence-identity
```

Comment: Bhushan So what does this mean? "By default, the Id annotation will automatically determine the most appropriate primary key generation strategy to use—you can override this by also applying the GeneratedValue annotation." Do I need to override the strategy every time?

Comment: @Steve as a i have mention when you just used `@Id` then  assigned strategy used means you will responsible to assign id for your entity not hibernate.
Also can you please brief me what do you mean by `I need to override the strategy every time?`

Comment: Like the book says by default '@Id' annotation will handle the primary key generation strategy to use. If one wants to change default strategy one can use '@GeneratedValue'. So my question is why isn't '@Id' handling the strategy for me. Why is it using default value of the int variable.

Comment: @Steve `@Id` only specifies the primary key of an entity, it is not responsible to auto assign the value of id, If you used on @Id , by default the @Id annotation will automatically determine the  `assigned strategy` means application will assign an identifier(id value) to the object before save() or persist()  is called (mean you will write the code where you will  assign  the value of id before entity save).
So if you need auto generated Id value then you need to use  @GeneratedValue  or another hibernate generator strategy which will take care of auto assign the value of id

Comment: Now that m using `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)`on id field, the code is working fine. But I tried using the same code on another machine, I am getting an exception trace. `Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist`. Is this a db related issue

Comment: Hibernate is trying to run this query `Hibernate: select hibernate_sequence.nextval from dual` and this has been causing the aforementioned exception.

Comment: are you using oracle database? and SequenceGenerator ?

Comment: Yes, m using Oracle DB on both the systems. The code is working fine on one system but giving exception on other. Note: I am using @GeneratedValue annotation now.

Comment: looks like it's oracle db issue,you should create a sequence (let's call it VEHICLE_SEQ). Then you should put this annotations on your id:
in your java code:
`@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "SEQ")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ", sequenceName = "VEHICLE_SEQ")`
To create the sequence in db:
`CREATE SEQUENCE VEHICLE_SEQ START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;`

Comment: Thanx for the sequence generator query. Can I try reinstalling the database? Coz if the same code is working on one machine, it should work on others as well. Right?

Comment: sorry! man i have not much worked around the oracle db, so don't have much idea about it